# Need help in array manipulation (php)

Tags: php, arrays

I have this $record array

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(2) { ["ROLE_ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]=> string(3) "904" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["ROLE_ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]=> string(3) "903" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["ROLE_ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]=> string(3) "902" } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["ROLE_ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]=> string(3) "901" } 
}
```

How can i manipulate it so it will become like this?

```
array("901","902","903","904");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$subfunctionIds = array();

foreach($record as $values) {
   $subFunctionIds[] = $values['SUBFUNCTION_ID'];
}

// If you want them reversed like in your example output...
$subFunctionIds = array_reverse($subFunctionIds);

var_dump($subFunctionIds);
```

Comment: Thanks alex! I cant believe it is that simple :D

Answer (score 2):

```
    function fetch($row) {
       return $row["SUBFUNCTION_ID"];
    }
    $result = array_map("fetch", $record);
    sort($result);
    var_dump($result);
```

in 5.3+ you could do better:

```
    $result = array_map(function ($row) { return $row["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]; }, $record);
    sort($result);
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: The anonymous function is indeed much clearer - however, pre 5.3 it is kind of ugly (having to define a named function) :P

Comment: @alex you could use `create_function()` in pre-5.3, but I don't want to stuff too much into one answer :)

Comment: Yeah, but it is not very pretty either. Looks just like a wrapper for `eval()`. +1 for `array_map` and anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
foreach ($array as $row ) {   
  $response[] = $row["SUBFUNCTION_ID"]; 
}
print_r($response);
```

Comment: That will have `$response` equal to the last variable.

Comment: you're missing the `[]` in `$response[] = $row['SUBFUNCTION_ID'];`. This will only print the last ID

Comment: @Samuel Herzog He'll also get a warning if `$response` is not an array.